# Why can't I Bus.Reply() to myself in NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus

When my endpoint does `Bus.Reply()` to I a message sent with `Bus.SendLocal()`, I get the following error message which causes the message to fail:

```
2013-02-28 13:54:16,994 [Worker.15] WARN  NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transact
ional.TransactionalTransport [(null)] <(null)> - Failed raising 'transport messa
ge received' event for message with ID=42e4b3ed-d0a2-4ab0-acfb-3531d8dafa3e\2056
7
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportMessageHandlingFailedException: Exception
 of type 'NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportMessageHandlingFailedException'
 was thrown.
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleTransportMessage(IBuilder childBuilde
r, TransportMessage msg) in c:\BuildAgent\work\nsb.master_6\src\unicast\NService
Bus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 1331
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender, Tra
nsportMessageReceivedEventArgs e) in c:\BuildAgent\work\nsb.master_6\src\unicast
\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 1248
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.OnTrans
portMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg) in c:\BuildAgent\work\nsb.master_6\src
\impl\unicast\transport\NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional\Transactiona
lTransport.cs:line 480
```

Here's my configuration:

```
 Configure
     .With(AllAssemblies.Except("evointernal.dll")) // This is a COM assembly and should not be scanned.
     .StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container)
     .JsonSerializer()
     .UnicastBus().DoNotAutoSubscribe()
     .Sagas();
```

Comment: can you add your configuration file settings?

Comment: Ricardo, I'm still working on better isolating the problem and will post an update when I know what's up a little better.  (The entire problem in this question may change.)